# Is there any truth to the myth of Polybius?

Tags: gaming-history

There is an old urban legend about an arcade game Polybius.

An arcade machine that would have been made to be a government experiment, appeared just for a few days in a few arcades, and then some men in black took it away, never to be seen again.

So is there a nugget of truth to this myth? Did the game ever exist? Or was it all created from nothing just to be a creepypasta?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7X6Yeydgyg Is a video in the subject from a Youtube game historian, for lack of a better term.

Comment: [Skeptics SE also answered this](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/2720/6523)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The game never existed. Both [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polybius_(urban_legend)) and [Snopes](https://www.snopes.com/inboxer/hoaxes/roundup.asp) state this definitively.

One theory for the creation of this urban legend is that is was started by Kurt Koller in an effort to get more visitors to his site dedicated to arcade gaming.

Comment: Specifically I'm pretty sure that the [RetroAhoy video on Polybius](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7X6Yeydgyg) is the main proponent of the "it's all Kurt Koller advertising for CoinOp.org" theory - the channel dug through old references to the game, and didn't find any from before the CoinOp.org article on the game aside from a reference that was obviously back-dated.

Answer (score -6):

The game existed. I know facts of Polybius that has never been posted on the internet. I have tested four times. Read my reddit post and then try telling me it didn't exist. https://www.reddit.com/r/VideoGameConspiracies/comments/8paxrv/the_polybius_truth/

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. it is best to quote the relevant information from the link in the event the linked site was to go down

Comment: I read the reddit post.  It doesn't exist.  Your reddit post reads like a fiction novel.  It's says a lot; but offers no evidence or way to prove what you've claimed.